# Locale and ISO3CountryCodes

Tags: java, locale, gregorian-calendar, iso-3166

I have seen recently in java 1.7 that if I loop on Locales and get the ISO3Country code for the same then for Locale "CS"  it gives me error "couldn't find 3 letter country code CS". Is it expected behavior?
I also tested in java 1.6 but there I am not getting this error.

```
Locales[] locales =        GregorianCalender.getAvailableLocales();
For(Locale l: locales){
     System.out.println(l.getISO3CountryCode());
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: This is a country code for a country that no longer exists (Serbia and Montenegro), so the behavior may indeed be indeterminate.

ISO-3166 is divided into three parts. The first part, ISO-3166-1, defines these country codes and, in turn, has several parts. The most relevant here are [ISO-3166-1 alpha-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2) and [ISO-3166-1 alpha-3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-3) which define the 2 and 3-letter country codes, respectively.

According to the alpha-2 table, "CS" is the country code for Serbia and Montenegro, a country that no longer exists. It still has an entry in alpha-2, marked as "reserved for deletion", for backwards compatibility purposes. It is probably also still in Java for backwards compatibility.

The equivalent entry in alpha-3 is "SCG" and is also be marked as reserved. I would expect this code to be returned to you, but can understand why it might not be. (Alternatively, [ISO-3166-3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-3) defines country codes for countries that no longer exist; they are four letters long and maybe "CSXX" is what should be returned here...)